# Can Spring XD be configured to have the File Channel functionality of Flume?

Tags: java, hadoop, flume, spring-xd

I have a prototype that uses Flume, and would like to port it to Spring XD. Everything looks good, but I cant find the Channel abstraction of Flume.

Can I configure Spring XD to store any undeliverable files on disk until they are deliverable again?

I need to send audio files from remote collectors to a centralized HDFS with possibly more than one Spring XD instance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might help your case: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#csv-hdfs

That enables you run the file->hdfs as a batch job.

If you want to run it as stream you can setup a stream like `file | hdfs`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I can use flume for transport from the remote (since it looks more reliable to me) site and then Spring to feed it to hdfs so I get all the reports, taps and all the fancy stuff that I miss from flume.